# Deactivate UIScrollView decelerating

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0, uiscrollview

Is there a way to deactivate the decelerating of a UIScrollView?

I want to allow the user to scroll the canvas, but I don't want that the canvas continues scrolling after the user lifted the finger.

Comment: Adam,
I'm aware that changing the default behavior isn't recommend but I think in my special case it would make sense. I'm implementing an extended canvas with the ability to edit objects directly on the canvas. When entering this on-canvas-edit mode I would like to restrict the distance the user scrolls so that the object is alway in the visible range. The use is allowed to scroll further, but it would bounce back on finger up. I'm aware of the contentSize property, but it interferes with my growing canvas.

Comment: In my situation, we were doing paid for hire work and the client requested that we remove the deceleration motion.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

This can be done by utilizing the `UIScrollView` delegate method `scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating` to automatically set the content offset to the current screen position.

To implement:

1. Assign a delegate to your `UIScrollView` object if you have not already done so.
2. In your delegate's `.m` implementation file, add the following lines of code:

   ```
   -(void)scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{  
       [scrollView setContentOffset:scrollView.contentOffset animated:YES];   
   }
   ```

Voila! No more auto-scroll.

Comment: Mine jumps to where the deceleration would have ended back to where it started... Any suggestions?

Comment: I found using this method will interfere with touch events in the view being zoomed. (In my case I had some buttons in the view that became inactive when zoomed out.) Using Quotation's fix below fixed the issue.

Comment: This does seem to work but i am hesitant to use something that no-one can seem to explain. Mark could you clarify as to why this works?

Comment: Thomas Clowes: The above solution was written long ago and is something of a hack. When the scroll view deceleration animation begins, it calls the delegate method scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating, and my one line of code simply manually forces the content offset (think of this as the visible portion of the scroll view) to stay at whatever position it was already at, forcing no visual change. These days, I'd recommend using the delegate method pointed out below by Quotation. Set the targetContentOffset to the current offset to prevent motion.

Answer (score 44):

For iOS 5.0 or later, there is a better method than calling `setContentOffset:animated:`.

Implement delegate method `scrollViewWillEndDragging:withVelocity:targetContentOffset:` in your `.m` file:

```
- (void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
                     withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity
              targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset {
    targetContentOffset.pointee = scrollView.contentOffset;
}
```

Assigning the current offset to `targetContentOffset` stops the `UIScrollView` from auto-scrolling.

Answer (score 21):

You can just turn up the deceleration rate very high.  With an infinite rate, it would stop immediately.  Try setting the rate to these constants:

```
scrollView.decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateNormal;
```

and

```
scrollView.decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast;
```

If fast still isn't fast enough for you, UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast is just typedef'ed as a float, so you can just multiply it by a factor of 10 or so to speed it up even more.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried various values for the decelerationRate property, but didn't manage to make the deceleration appear non existence. A quick swipe always makes the scrollview scroll a considerable amount.

Comment: In my experience, the `decelerationRate` property only responds to the values explicated in the documentation: `UIScrollViewDecelerationRateNormal` and `UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast`.

Comment: This is great, as it still enables the content to not go past the desired bounds. When implementing the other options, I could pan the content farther than desired.

Comment: If you want to prevent that from happening set `scrollView.bounces = false`

Answer (score 1):

Just set the decelerationRate property to 0

It will disable the auto scrolling property. But keep in mind the user interaction will become bad if scrollview contentsize is big.