# How can I make my UIScrollView move only when I drag it?

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

I don't want the UIScrollView to scroll. But only move when I drag it. So that it stopes when i take the fingers of it. I have placed a lot of imageViews on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105647/deactivate-uiscrollview-decelerating)

Comment: Wow, Its amazing that there is such a simple solution for which I have been searching for almost 2 days.