# How to set UITableView to snap to closest cell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

So what I am trying to achieve in my app is have a UITableView that when the user scrolls, snaps to the closest cell there is. So if I have 3 cells, and the user scrolls, if the user is closest to the top of the second cell, snap the UITableView there.

Hopefully I have conveyed the feature I am trying to achieve. I have done some basic research, and have found this method, `scrollViewWillEndDragging:withVelocity:targetContentOffset:`, but I am not familiar with this method and how it works.

Any help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Want UITableView to "snap to cell"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16088615/want-uitableview-to-snap-to-cell)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your cells are all a fixed height, just take a look at the targetContentOffset.y, and then round it to your nearest cell height:

```
targetContentOffset->y = floorf(targetContentOffset->y / self.rowHeight) * self.rowHeight
```

Comment: So just implementing scrollViewWillEndDragging:withVelocity:targetContentOffset: and that line should do the trick?

Comment: not sure host the rest of your code is laid out, but if there's nothing funky going on, that's it.

Comment: And what if they are all different heights?