# How to stop UIScrollView when fingers are lifted (Swift 4)

Tags: ios, swift

How do I stop a scrollView when the user lifts their fingers instead of just bouncing back to the top?

```
var displayData = UITextView()

func displayTallTable() {

    displayData.text = outputString
    
    // getFrameBounds (x, y, width, height)
    displayData.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: w, height: h)
    
    self.addSubview(scrollView)
    scrollView.addSubview(displayData)

    let g = self.safeAreaLayoutGuide
    
    scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor).isActive = true
    scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor).isActive = true        
}
```

I can drag the view up but when I lift my fingers, it just bounces back to the top.

So, I added `UIScrollViewDelegate` to the class:
`class TallView: UIView, UIScrollViewDelegate { ... }`

and have tried the following, none of which is called:

```
func scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    debugPrint("scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating")
}
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    debugPrint("scrollViewDidScroll")
}
func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    debugPrint("scrollViewWillBeginDragging")
}
func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
    debugPrint("scrollViewWillEndDragging")
}
func scrollViewDidChangeAdjustedContentInset(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    debugPrint("scrollViewDidChangeAdjustedContentInset")
}
```

It seems that :

```
func killScroll() {
    self.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false;
    self.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = true;
}
```

(from: [How can I programmatically force-stop scrolling in a UIScrollView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410777/how-can-i-programmatically-force-stop-scrolling-in-a-uiscrollview)) should do the trick, but I don't know what should be calling it.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you may want this this effect:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if !scrollView.isTracking {
            let contentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset
            // if you want to locate to the top, you could set: let contentOffset = CGPoint.zero
            scrollView.setContentOffset(contentOffset, animated: false)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have that function above (without the contents) but it is never called.  What would cause it to be called?

Comment: Have you set delegete like this:
scrollView.delegate = self

Comment: Yes, I tried that both inside ````override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) ```` and inside ````func displayTallTable()````

Comment: I saw your code: `scrollView.addSubview(displayData)`, but `displayData` is UITextView's object, that is an another scrollview.  may be it is `displayData` that disable your scrollView's gesture, after all, `displayData` has its own gesture.

Comment: Sounds like I have the wrong approach?  I originally created the UITextView then discovered it could be much longer than the screen height (especially when I landscape),  so I put inside the scrollView.  Is there a better, or correct, way to accomplish this?

Comment: I am sorry, I am not sure I understand your question.  But it is better not to put `UITextView` inside `UIScrollView `, as they are both `UIScrollView `.

Comment: Well, that is actually part of a solution.  How would I force the UITextView to stop scrolling when fingers are removed from the screen?

Comment: If your scrollView delegate could be called,  my code in answer can stop ti

Comment: Ok, I'm learning something and feel like I'm getting somewhere!  I've removed the scrollView to leave just the textView ````displayData````, replaced ````class TallView: UIView, UIScrollViewDelegate { ... }```` with ````class TallView: UIView, UITextViewDelegate { ... }````, and replaced ````scrollView.delegate```` with ````displayData.delegate = self````.  But I am still stumped on what function will get called when scroll and release...

Comment: when you scroll `displayData `, `scrollViewDidScroll ` will be called, when your finger is on the screen, `scrollView.isTracking` is true, when your finger is lifted, `scrollView.isTracking` is false