# Disable UIScrollView inertia (scrollViewDidEndDecelerating) Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, swipe

**Setup:** I have a Scroll View that works great horizontally as well as a UISwipeGestureRecognizer that triggers a segue to another view when I swipe down.

**Problem:** If I am scrolling horizontally and I begin to swipe down (vertical scrolling disabled) **WHILE the scrolling is decelerating**, the swipe down action (segue) does not execute. It only works once the scrolling deceleration is complete.

[image]

Is there a way to disable the scroll deceleration (aka inertia) so that my swipe down gesture can be detected instantly? Perhaps there's a workaround to force UISwipeGestureRecognizer to be detected first?

Solutions in Swift are highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIScrollView has a `pinchGestureRecognizer` and a `panGestureRecognizer`.If you have a `UISwipeGestureRecognizer`,the gesture will most likely be recognized as a `UIPanGestureRecognizer`.
You can add a dependence to solve the problem:

```
scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.requireGestureRecognizerToFail(swipeGesture)
```

Comment: This actually helped me achieve what I originally wanted. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

did you look here?
[Deactivate UIScrollView decelerating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105647/deactivate-uiscrollview-decelerating)

the answer

```
-(void)scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{  
[scrollView setContentOffset:scrollView.contentOffset animated:YES];   
}
```

converted to swift is

```
func scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
scrollView.setContentOffset(scrollView.contentOffset, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I have tried that solution a few minutes ago and found that it interferes with my `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` swipe down detection. None of my gestures are detected once I use the scrollview due to that hack in the BeginDecelerating. Perhaps another hack in EndDecelerating as a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3**:

To disable decelerating scroll you can try:

```
func scrollViewWillEndDragging (scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
    targetContentOffset.memory = scrollView.contentOffset
}
```

or you change this value:

```
scrollView.decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateNormal
// UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast is the other param
```

About your gestureRecognizer interferences you can call this method to exclude touching from:

```
func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceiveTouch touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
    // insert here views to exclude from gesture
    if touch.view!.isDescendantOfView(self.excludeThisView) {
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: I did not know about `scrollViewWillEndDragging` and it looks very interesting. I tried it with `targetContentOffset.memory = scrollView.contentOffset` and it had no effect. For some reason, my `gestureRecognizer` is still delayed by the deceleration (or any bounce) in my scrollView. My goal is to allow `gestureRecognizer` to execute instantly without being delayed by any scrolling deceleration.

Comment: targetContentOffset is now a let var. cannot be mutated